# Error while adding an observer to a player

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x1702076f0
>   of class AVPlayerItem was deallocated while key value observers were
>   still registered with it. Current observation info:
>    (
>
> (.<)NSKeyValueObservance 0x174846360: Observer: 0x174846210, Key path:
>   loadedTimeRanges, Options:  Context:
>   0x0, Property: 0x1748462d0> )'

This is the error i am receiving after adding the **currentItem.loadedTimeRanges** observer to my AVPlayer

```
player = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl!)
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = postVideoView.frame
        playerLayer.frame.size.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        self.postVideoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player?.play()
        player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: .new, context: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem, queue: nil, using: { (_) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.player?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
                self.player?.play()
            }
        })
    }


override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    //this is when the player is ready and rendering frames
    if keyPath == "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges" {
        if let duration = player?.currentItem?.duration {
            let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)

            let secondsText = Int(seconds) % 60
            let minutesText = String(format: "%02d", Int(seconds) / 60)
            videoLengthLabel.text = "\(minutesText):\(secondsText)"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you call `removeObserver`? At the moment it looks like if your top code creates a new player and adds an observer. If this gets called twice the observer on the first instance will still exist. Therefore I would expect the following line at the top:

```
self.player?.removeObserver(self)
```

If it isn't being called twice, is there anywhere else in the code where `self.player` is reallocated or deallocated? If so, you should first be calling `removeObserver`.

You are also adding a new observer to NotificationCenter every time. This should either only ever be called once or `removeObserver` before adding another.

Comment: I am calling in a table view cell method. Is this the issue. Otherwise how can i get around it

Comment: It's hard to understand the flow of your code - you probably need to include more in your question, like how `player = ...` gets called, and the code for `removeObserver`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are not adding and removing the observer more than once. So best way is just declare one bool variable lets say `var isObserverAdded = false.`

While adding the observer check this flag if not added

```
if !isObserverAdded {
//Add your observer
isObserverAdded = true//Set this to true
}
```

While removing the observer check the flag if added

```
if isObserverAdded {
//Add your observer
isObserverAdded = false//Set this to false
}
```

If use the above check then you will never get the error.